# elki-cli versus elki gui, I don't get equal results

Tags: data-mining, elki

Though the terminal on ubuntu:

```
db@morris:~/lisbet/elki-master/elki/target$ elki-cli -algorithm outlier.lof.LOF -dbc.parser ArffParser -dbc.in /home/db/lisbet/AllData/literature/WBC/WBC_withoutdupl_norm_v10_no_ids.arff -lof.k 8 -evaluator outlier.OutlierROCCurve -rocauc.positive yes
```

giving 
`# ROCAUC: 0.6230046948356808`

and in ELKI's GUI:

```
Running: -verbose -dbc.in /home/db/lisbet/AllData/literature/WBC/WBC_withoutdupl_norm_v10_no_ids.arff -dbc.parser ArffParser -algorithm outlier.lof.LOF -lof.k 8 -evaluator outlier.OutlierROCCurve -rocauc.positive yes
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.FileBasedDatabaseConnection.parse: 18 ms
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.FileBasedDatabaseConnection.filter: 0 ms
LOF #1/3: Materializing LOF neighborhoods.
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.preprocessed.knn.MaterializeKNNPreprocessor.k: 9
Materializing k nearest neighbors (k=9): 223 [100%]
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.preprocessed.knn.MaterializeKNNPreprocessor.precomputation-time: 10 ms
LOF #2/3: Computing LRDs.
LOF #3/3: Computing LOFs.
LOF: complete.
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.algorithm.outlier.lof.LOF.runtime: 39 ms
ROCAUC: **0.6220657276995305**
```

I don't understand why the 2 ROCAUCcurves aren't the same.

*My goal in testing this is to be comfortable with my result, that what I do is right, but it is hard when I don't get matching results. When I see that my settings are right I will move on to making my own experiments, that I can trust.*

Comment: Same version? Try `elki-cli -h | head`. This appears to be a packaged Ubuntu version, and that is 0.6.0 for me, not the latest.

Comment: db@morris:~/lisbet/elki-master/elki/target$ elki-cli -h | head
ELKI Version 0.6.0 (2014, January)
Yes...correct

Comment: But when I run:
db@morris:~/lisbet/elki-master/elki/target$ java -jar elki-0.6.5-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/db/lisbet/elki-master/elki/src/main/java/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/application/KDDCLIApplication 
it opens the GUI and I wanted to try if I could just do it in the terminal, without the GUI.

Comment: You have to pass a *Java class* name, not a path name. I.e. `java -jar elki-0.6.5-SNAPSHOT.jar KDDCLIApplication` or `java -jar elki-0.6.5-SNAPSHOT.jar de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.K‌​DDCLIApplication`.

Comment: Try varying `k` by `+-1`, and check if you get the same result then. We changed the `k` parameter to be more consistent in ELKI, even if this means being less consistent with literature (which is inconsistent itself).

Comment: They became exactly the same, when I didn't use elki-cli but just cli or KDDCLIApplication. 
In my head the ubuntu version must be old then, or is it only the printing that wasn't updated. 
I am satisfied with the results I get from 0.6.5 and gitversion (they are the same, so I guess there hasn't been updates). But when I compare my results to a recent article's results from a spreadsheet, they aren't the same. That made me wonder if I did something wrong.

I do get a bit different AUCROCcurve from whenI used 0.6.0 to when I used 0.6.5, so some improvement must have happened inbetween.

Comment: There are plenty of changes inbetween 0.6.5 and git; but probably none you would notice in the AUC value as much as changing the way the k-nearest-neighbors are defined. Really do this, because that may be the difference to that very spreadsheet that they used a different definition of k... (it would also be helpful if you would name that article.)

Answer (score 2):

Pass `cli` as first command line parameter to launche the CLI, or `minigui` to launch the MiniGUI. The following are equivalent:

```
java -jar elki/target/elki-0.6.5-SNAPSHOT.jar cli
java -jar elki/target/elki-0.6.5-SNAPSHOT.jar KDDCLIApplication
java -jar elki/target/elki-0.6.5-SNAPSHOT.jar de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.KDDCLIApplication
```

This will work for any class extending the class `AbstractApplication`.

Your can also do:

```
java -cp elki/target/elki-0.6.5-SNAPSHOT.jar de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.KDDCLIApplication
```

(Which will load 1 class less, but this is usually not worth the effort.)

This will work for any class that has a standard `public void main(String[])` method, as this is the standard Java invocation.

But notice that `-h` currently will still print `0.6.0 (2014, January)`, that value was not updated for the 0.6.5 interim versions. It will be bumped for `0.7.0`. That version number is therefore not reliable.

As for the differences you observed: try varing `k` by 1. If I recall correctly, we changed the meaning of the k parameter to be more consistent across different algorithms. (They are not consistent in literature anyway.)